# How to add a shadow effect to the ListView in the DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, listview, drawerlayout, drop-shadow

I have a slidermenu which is generated using a listView. This Listview is placed inside a DrawerLayout. I want to add a drop shadow effect to the ListView. Can anyone tell me step by step what to do?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm getting from the question is that you wanna add a shadow to the navigation drawer menu.

Here is the sample

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout); // referring the drawer layout from the xml file

drawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START); //setting the drawer shadow
```

Make sure you put the nine-patch drawable *drawer_shadow.9.png* inside your drawable folders. You can find the image in sdk folder *android-sdk\extras\android\support\samples\Support4Demos\res* .